# When to not "svn commit && svn update"?

Tags: svn, commit

By no means a svn expert, I am wondering in what scenarios would you **not** want to `svn update` immediately after performing a `svn commit`, assuming* you are committing everything in your working copy. Any practical examples/scenarios?

In other words, why shouldn't everyone using SVN have an alias/function in place such as `svn commit && svn update`? (disregarding `commit`'s `-m` flag)

* *I cite this assumption because I think it's generally supported to be a best practice when developing under version control, although there are of course occasional times to cut corners on this and I suspect that's the primary answer to my question.*

Comment: I think part of this is related to the fact SVN is a CVCS as opposed to a DVCS (e.g. git/hg).

Comment: I personally update first, then commit. If there are conflicts, committing first will just fail anyway.

Comment: Right. Perhaps it's worth clarifying that all updating (including resolving any conflicts), re-building, and testing has been performed so now you're ready to really commit. That's the starting point for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right. Perhaps it's worth clarifying that all updating (including
>   resolving any conflicts), re-building, and testing has been performed
>   so now you're ready to really commit. That's the starting point for my
>   question.

I can't think up a case when you should not or must not run `svn update` after running `svn commit`. Assuming that all the stuff quoted above has been performed, why not to do an `svn update`? At the same time, why would you want to run `svn update`?

Run `svn update` the next time you start working on the task, the next time you see commits in the feature branch you are working on (or any other branch or trunk that you are workin on at that moment) and make sure to run `svn update` before you commit your changes.

The main rule here is to run `svn update` often to ensure that there are no conflicts with your work and the work of others (assuming you modify the same files).

Read SVNBook:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs.update-commit
- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html

Comment: "At the same time, why would you want to run svn update?" Because until I do, I do not see my commit in the log ( `svn log` ) even though the committed files are up-to-date. This also makes me wonder what else, other than the log, is left out-of-sync with the central repo.

Comment: This is running Cygwin under Windows10 with the cygwin svn v1.9.3

Comment: @tniles09 why don't you run native svn client foe Windows?

Comment: why should I? I'm working in cygwin, and cygwin has an svn package (and if I'm not mistaken, it's not all that old of a version, but rather up-to-date)

Answer (score 2):

What I actually use is a bash function for `svn update && svn commit` (with added -m, but I guess that depends on your preferences for how to submit commit messages).

It *could* be `svn update && svn commit && svn update`, but unless you're working with a very large repository, odds are that your repository won't be significantly changed between the first and last updates.